# Proof Verification : Equivalent Condition for Locally Connected Space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, locally-connected

A topological space $X$ is locally connected if

> for every $x$ in $X$ and for every open set $V$ containing $x$, there is a connected open set $U$ with $x \in U \subset V$.

I think it is equivalent to the following statement:

> For $X$, there is a basis all of whose elements are open and connected.

One way (Assume the latter, and prove that $X$ is locally connected) is trivial.

Let's prove the other way. (Assume that $X$ is locally connected.)

Let $\tau$ be the set $\{U : U ~\text{is open and connected}\}$.
We shall show that $\tau$ is a basis.

Becasue $X$ is locally connected, for every $x \in X$ (if we put $V = X$) there is a
connected open set $U_x$ with $x \in U_x \subset X$.

Hence, $\{U_x : x \in X\} \subset \tau$.
Because $\{U_x : x \in X\}$ covers $X$,
we know that $\tau$ covers $X$.

For any $V_1, V_2 \in \tau$, the set $V_1 \cap V_2$ is an open set.

Because $X$ is locally connected,
for every $x \in V_1 \cap V_2$,
there is $W_x$ which is open and connected
with $x \in W_x \subset V_1 \cap V_2$.

Note that $W_x$ belongs to $\tau$. Hence, $\tau$ satisfies all conditions for being a basis.

---

Please check my (above) proof is right.

And I think the same argument is available to the locally path-connected space. Please, give me an advice.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of *$N$ is a neighborhood of $x$*? For many of us it means that $x$ is in the interior of $N$ but does not imply that $N$ is open, and by that definition your sets $U_x$ are not necessarily in $\tau$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I edit it. Thank you for letting me know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you prove is correct, but it is not that what is required.

In fact it is fairly obvious that the set $\mathcal U$
of all connected open $U \subset X$ forms a *basis for the topolopy on $X$*: For each  open $V \subset X$ and each $x \in V$ there exists $U \in \mathcal U$ such that $x \in U \subset V$.

What you prove is that $\mathcal U$ satisfies the conditions for an *abstract basis on the set $X$*, i.e. that $\mathcal U$ is the basis for **some** topology on $X$. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)).

For the locally path connected case everything works literally as above.